# xtoolkit - volume.range is undefined

Tags: xtk

volume.range is undefined

here is a part from the code :

```
    var sliceXController = volumegui.add(volume, 'indexX', 0,
        volume.range[0] - 1);
    var sliceYController = volumegui.add(volume, 'indexY', 0,
        volume.range[1] - 1);
    var sliceZController = volumegui.add(volume, 'indexZ', 0,
        volume.range[2] - 1);
    volumegui.open();
```

and here is the full code from lesson13 :
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/toolkit/edge/xtk/lessons/tree/master/13/#run

what should i do now and thanks a lot

Comment: Can you share your code? Lesson 13 is working so you must be doing something wrong but we can't help you without your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you get this to work? I'm new to XTK and had problems with this when loading my own NRRD/NII files. I changed volume.range[0] to volume.dimensions[0] (etc.) and that worked fine for me, but not sure if that's a legit way of fixing things.

Edit: Actually, check which build you are using. I switched to xtk_edge.js and volume.range works fine with that build.

[https://github.com/xtk/ge](https://github.com/xtk/get)